# Use of the "-=" operator with array element in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, operators, arithmetic-expressions

Following code deletes the 7th character and beyond from string I figured this out but can anyone clarify me the general logic of an array and operations like `S1[6] -= S1[6];`. I searched array arithmetic but it relates with address arithmetic and pointers. Thanks for the help.

```
#include <string.h>

int main()   
{ 
   char S1[]= "Hello World";   
   S1[6] -= S1[6];
   printf("%s",S1);
}
```

Comment: It simply sets that character to `0` so`printf` stops printing there. If you want to actually delete, i.e. completely remove a character, then you need to move left by one all chars to the right including `0` terminator. Array will still have the same size though. If array 
 also must resize, then it has to be dynamically allocated and not on the stack as it is now, so you can `realloc` it to a smaller size (with all the necessary checks ofc).
Operator `-=` subtracts the right side from the left, and then assigns the result back to the left. So, `a -= b;` is equivalent to `a = a - b;`

Comment: The `-=` operator is unrelated to arrays. `S1[6] -= S1[6]` is very poor C code for `S1[6] = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
S1[6] -= S1[6];
```

is equal to

```
S1[6] = S1[6] - S1[6];
```

which is also equivalent to

```
S1[6] = 0;
```

or better in the context

```
S1[6] = '\0';
```

---

`S1[6]`, the `7`th element of array `S1` with the value of the `'W'` character is subtracted by itself and the result, actually `0`, is assigned back to the `7`th array element.

It makes the `7`th element of the string a null character, which terminates the string, although all characters which come after the `7`th element aren´t overwritten/erased.

This has the effect, that the output of your program will be `"Hello "` instead of `"Hello World"`.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment, I don't know why they wrote the code like that instead just equal it to 0.

Comment: It can be used as a plagiarism indicator.  If someone steals such source, it is easily identifiable.

Comment: @MartinJames :-)

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
 S1[6] -= S1[6];
```

can be read as

```
S1[6] = S1[6] - S1[6];
```

So basically, it's subtracting the value of the array instance itself, so as to make the 7th. element as 0.

However, this does not change the value of any other element in the array (not like what you mentioned as "7th character and beyond.."), it just makes the value of 7th element as `0`, which is the terminating null character for a *string*. So, after the modification, when you pass the array to a function which expects string, up to the null terminator is only *visible*.

Comment: So it basically means that make 7th element and so forth zero?

Comment: No, `x = x - x` is just a convoluted way to say `x = 0`. I'd fire a programmer that writes code like this.

Comment: @IDK No. As mentionned, only the 7th element will be 0. But a 0 means "end of string", so the following elements aren't even considered on string processing.

Comment: @IDK Not so forth, only the 7th element.

Answer (score 1):

As this line of code  S1[6] -= S1[6]; will produce zero so when you execute your code to print  hello word string it will print from the start till null terminator so it will print the first 5 character only